# angular ajax not correct serialization date

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am using angular ajax sumit a data, it contains a date, looks like below,[image]

it is correct, but when I check the browser'ajax records, there is one day less, refer to below,
[image]

how can I use $httpProvider make it correct?

Comment: That's in UTC time zone. What date format does the server support? Are you sure the server is not allowing T format date.

Comment: @cgTag,Nothing with the server format support, The second picture is submit data headers, When it submit one day less. So I think it is a serialization issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a javascript Date.toJSON() issue, By default it get the UTC time, but I am not in that time zone, so I should overwrite it likes below,

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    return this.getTime();
};
```

now it correct.

Comment: Now you have two bugs.